# Edge label overlap

Tags: graphviz, dot

In the `DOT` language, I am trying to represent a simple weighted undirected graph. But is there any way to make sure the edge labels don't overlap with the edges. For example, I am getting the following image, where the edge labels overlap with the edges, and it is hard to guess, which label corresponds to which edge. How can we fix these two problems? And is there any other way we can improve the output.

[image]

The dot file contents are as follows :

```
graph G  {    
 layout=fdp; 
 splines=true;
 overlap=scalexy; 
 sep="+10,10"; 
 color=blue; 
 node [ width = 0.05, height = 0.05 , fontsize=10 , style=filled ]
 1 -- 5  [ label =  "1" , fontsize= 10 ];
 1 -- 6  [ label =  "19" , fontsize= 10 ];
 1 -- 7  [ label =  "2" , fontsize= 10 ];
 1 -- 8  [ label =  "3" , fontsize= 10 ];
 2 -- 5  [ label =  "8" , fontsize= 10 ];
 2 -- 6  [ label =  "13" , fontsize= 10 ];
 3 -- 4  [ label =  "10" , fontsize= 10 ];
 3 -- 5  [ label =  "28" , fontsize= 10 ];
 3 -- 6  [ label =  "4" , fontsize= 10 ];
 4 -- 7  [ label =  "14" , fontsize= 10 ];
 4 -- 8  [ label =  "12" , fontsize= 10 ];
 5 -- 6  [ label =  "16" , fontsize= 10 ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you might be able to improve the output is by colouring corresponding edges and labels the same colour. You could use a different colour for each edge, or re-use the colours as long as they don't appear close to other edges of the same colours.